# Laptop's Camera window not being displayed, when using it for object detection using yolov8

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, yolov8

In the code given below, I was trying to do object detection using yolov8 through my laptop's camera, but the camera turns for 3-5 seconds and also the camera's window does not pop up.
I will be grateful for any help given.

Code:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import cv2
from time import time
from ultralytics import YOLO
import supervision as sv

class ObjectDetection:

    def __init__(self, capture_index):
       
        self.capture_index = capture_index
        
        self.device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
        print("Using Device: ", self.device)
        
        self.model = self.load_model()
        
        self.CLASS_NAMES_DICT = self.model.model.names
    
        self.box_annotator = sv.BoxAnnotator(sv.ColorPalette.default(), thickness=3, text_thickness=3, text_scale=1.5)
    

    def load_model(self):
       
        model = YOLO("yolov8m.pt")  # load a pretrained YOLOv8n model
        model.fuse()
    
        return model


    def predict(self, frame):
       
        results = self.model(frame)
        
        return results
    

    def plot_bboxes(self, results, frame):
        
        xyxys = []
        confidences = []
        class_ids = []
        
         # Extract detections for person class
        for result in results:
            boxes = result.boxes.cpu().numpy()
            class_id = boxes.cls[0]
            conf = boxes.conf[0]
            xyxy = boxes.xyxy[0]

            if class_id == 0.0:
          
              xyxys.append(result.boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy())
              confidences.append(result.boxes.conf.cpu().numpy())
              class_ids.append(result.boxes.cls.cpu().numpy().astype(int))
            
        
        # Setup detections for visualization
        detections = sv.Detections(
                    xyxy=results[0].boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy(),
                    confidence=results[0].boxes.conf.cpu().numpy(),
                    class_id=results[0].boxes.cls.cpu().numpy().astype(int),
                    )
        
    
        # Format custom labels
        self.labels = [f"{self.CLASS_NAMES_DICT[class_id]} {confidence:0.2f}"
        for _, confidence, class_id, tracker_id
        in detections]
        
        # Annotate and display frame
        frame = self.box_annotator.annotate(scene=frame, detections=detections, labels=self.labels)
        
        return frame
    
    
    
    def __call__(self):

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.capture_index)
        assert cap.isOpened()
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
      
        while True:
          
            start_time = time()
            
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            assert ret
            
            results = self.predict(frame)
            frame = self.plot_bboxes(results, frame)
            
            end_time = time()
            fps = 1/np.round(end_time - start_time, 2)
             
            cv2.putText(frame, f'FPS: {int(fps)}', (20,70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.5, (0,255,0), 2)
            
            cv2.imshow('YOLOv8 Detection', frame)
 
            if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
                
                break
        
        cap.release()
        
        
    
detector = ObjectDetection(capture_index=0)
detector()
```

I was trying to do object detection in yolo v8 through my web cam but the web cam's window is not opening.

Comment: welcome, [mre] please, including traceback or evidence of what *does* happen instead of what you expected. and you should describe the environment you're executing this in (colab?)

Comment: As I am executing the code, the window of the camera is not opening. The camera just turns on for 5 secs. I am executing this code in VSCODE